# Transformar "26/Fev/2013" em um OffsetDateTime (2013-02-26 00:00:00)

Tags: java

Dei um exemplo do mês de fevereiro, mas poderia ser Jan, Mar, etc...

Recebo uma **String** com o mês "abreviado" (somente a data como no título), quero converter isso para um 
[OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) sendo a ZoneOffset = UTC e o time padrão (00:00:00).

Alguma sugestão? 
Estou utilizando htmlUnit.

Comment: editei a pergunta, ficou mais claro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma opção é usar um `DateTimeFormatter` criado para esse formato:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY, 0)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
            .toFormatter(new Locale("pt"));
    OffsetDateTime offsetDT = OffsetDateTime.parse(texto, formatter);
```

Outra maneira semelhante:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy")
            .toFormatter(new Locale("pt"));
    LocalDate localD = LocalDate.parse(texto, formatter);
    OffsetDateTime offsetDT = OffsetDateTime.of(localD, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Explicação:

O uso do `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` é necessário para formatos mais *complicados*. Especificamente nesse caso para permitir a leitura de mêses com letra maiúscula (`parseCaseInsensitive()`) e, na primeira solução, adicionar um horário (`parseDefaulting(SECOND_OF_DAY...`) e uma zona (`parseDefaulting(OFFSET_SECONDS...`) nulos já que o texto não contêm esses campos. O `Locale("pt")` serve para que o mês seje interpretado em português.

Ao meu ver a segunda solução - transformar o texto em uma simples data, para depois *adicionar* o horário e a zona horário - é mais *correta* pois reflete melhor a intenção do código. Mas isso é apenas uma opinião baseada na atual pergunta...

*(não tenho certeza como essas soluções funcionam se o `Locale` default não for UTC...)*